# MingW environment paths

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw

I am trying to compile a simple program but the MingW C++ compiler cannot find the path. I have two files one is `C:\main.cpp` the other one is `C:\Include\test.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "test" << endl;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I have modified the CPATH, CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH enviroment vars to include the `C:\Include` path but it still will not compile with `g++ c:\main.cpp -o c:\main.exe`

Output from command line.

```
c:\main.cpp:2:18: fatal error: test.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Also I used this registry file. Still doesn't work.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment]
"LIBRARY_PATH"="C:\\Include"
"C_INCLUDE_PATH"="C:\\Include"
"CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH"="C:\\Include"
```

Comment: Using `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` works for me, using mingw-w64 4.9.2.  Maybe you forgot to export your environment vars?  If you are still having trouble then you should show in your question the exact way that you set up the environment and invoked the compiler, and what shell you are using, and what output you actually get.

Comment: @M.M Ah. Maybe I'll have to reinstall. Thanks! Post it as answer.

Comment: My comment isn't an answer  , unless you try exporting and find it starts working ..  an answer would explain for sure why it is not working for you currently

Comment: Maybe because I use TDM-GCC?

Answer (score 1):

There's not really enough information here, and storing source files in the root is suspect, but you might try:

g++ -I Include c:\main.cpp -o c:\main.exe

Assuming your cwd is C:\

Answer (score 0):

This plus system restart was needed.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment]
"LIBRARY_PATH"="C:\\Include"
"C_INCLUDE_PATH"="C:\\Include"
"CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH"="C:\\Include"
```